# Tab panel change content and footer

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab panel containing content that can be changed just by using the id in a tag

and each content has a different footer

how to make every time I change the page, footer also change

my code is like this

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <aside class="control-sidebar-ligth control-sidebar-open">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#first-content" data-toggle="tab">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second-content" data-toggle="tab">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third-content" data-toggle="tab">three</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="first-content"">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="second-content">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="third-content">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
<footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="active" id="first-content"><div>
    <div class="" id="second-content"><div>
    <div class="" id="third-content"><div>
</footer>
```

Comment: An ID should always be unique

Comment: do you mean there are two id on a tag?

Comment: can you be more descriptive and show us with example what is changing in above nav

Comment: @ramboeistblast you have `id="first-content"` twice, and others.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3

Comment: @AshishBalchandani i'm using tab from adminlte2, each tab containing the content and each content have difference footer